# How to select by time using doctrine 2?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a table in my database that stores my events data, and i am using Doctrine 2 as my ORM. I need to select from the table all the events that occur between 09:00AM and 13:00PM, doesn't matter the date. How can i accomplish this?
Note that i am not trying to compare dates. I didn't found any question in stack overflow with the answer i am searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySql, I think it will help [DATE_FORMAT in Doctrine2](http://www.uvd.co.uk/blog/labs/using-mysqls-date_format-in-doctrine-2-0/)